# How to print a python list, minus a specific element?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x

Given:

```
commands = dict(
   onboarding = dict(
      default = "default",
      status = "APPROVED",
      date = "11/18/15"
   )
   team = dict(
       members = getTeamMembers()
)
```

How do I

```
print commands['onboarding'].keys()
```

without printing the key 'default' in the list? I'm trying to hide that in my implementation. Bonus points if there's an explanation in both versions of python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
print [key for key in commands['onboarding'] if key != 'default']
```

Comment: My man! Thank you. Been looking around for a few hours now, the quick response is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you `from __future__ import print_function` you can get the following working with both versions:

```
d=commands['onboarding']
print(*[d[i] for i in d if i != 'default'])
```

where you build a list from all applicable keys and unpack in the `print` call. Of course, if you require a list in the output, don't unpack (i.e remove `*` from the beginning of the list comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `filter` like so for Python 2.7

```
print filter(lambda key: key != 'default', commands['onboarding'])
```

or like this in Python 3

```
print(list(filter(lambda key: key != 'default', commands['onboarding'])))
```

In Python 3, `filter` returns an iterable `filter` object and not a list as in Python 2, so you have to wrap it in `list()`